# JUnit 5 migration - how to solve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ReflectiveInvocationContext

Tags: java, junit4, junit5

When I run some JUnit 5 tests(there are also JUnit 4 tests in the same project, as we are in the process of migration towards JUnit 5), I see this error:

```
No tests were executed
...
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ReflectiveInvocationContext
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these dependencies in your `pom.xml`:

- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine

For JUnit 4:

- junit:4.12+
- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine (this only supports JUnit 4.12+)

And if you want to use @ParameterizedTest:

- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api
- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params

`org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher` is not needed, even you want to run the tests in Intellij. Maybe you can try w/o it.

```xml
        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- junit 5 parameterized tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for compatibility for JUnit 4. JUnit vintage needs 4.12+ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for compatibility for JUnit 4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit5.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for IDE support only(running tests from IDE) -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>1.7.1</version>-->
<!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
```